# Obtaining data from PostgreSQL as Dictionary

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a database table with multiple fields which I am querying and pulling out all data which meets certain parameters.  I am using psycopg2 for python with the following syntax:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM failed_inserts where insertid='%s' AND site_failure=True"%import_id)
                failed_sites= cur.fetchall()
```

This returns the correct values as a list with the data's integrity and order maintained.  However I want to query the list returned somewhere else in my application and I only have this list of values, i.e. it is not a dictionary with the fields as the keys for these values.  Rather than having to do

```
desiredValue = failed_sites[13] //where 13 is an arbitrary number of the index for desiredValue
```

I want to be able to query by the field name like:

```
desiredValue = failed_sites[fieldName] //where fieldName is the name of the field I am looking for
```

Is there a simple way and efficient way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cursor.description will give your the column information (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects). You can get the column names from it and use them to create a dictionary.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT ...')
columns = []
for column in cursor.description:
    columns.append(column[0].lower())
failed_sites = {}
for row in cursor:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        failed_sites[columns[i]] = row[i]
        if isinstance(row[i], str):
             failed_sites[columns[i]] = row[i].strip()
```

Since I live in a Python 3 world now, I've changed basestring to str in `isinstance()`.

Comment: thanks for this, i tried chatgpt and bard but only this answer helped. i think you need to replace basestring as str

Answer (score 1):

The ["Dictionary-like cursor"](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#connection-and-cursor-subclasses#dictionary-like-cursor), part of `psycopg2.extras`, seems what you're looking for.